# Remove UITableView scroll Indicators in tvOS

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos, tvos10

### Question:

How do I remove the vertical glowing scroll indicators in a TableView (or to change it's color) ?

### Description:

Since [UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview) I've been trying to find the cause behind it.
I've attempted to disable the scrolling indicators via the storyboard and via code like so:

```
//Where self is my TableViewController
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

but they have changed nothing. I've already gone in the storyboard and changed any default color to black. That didn't work either.

### Image:

[image: image showing the glowing scroll indicator]
*Image with red arrows pointing to the glowing white scroll indicator that I would like to remove OR to change it's color.*

### Edit: What I've tried:

I've attempted to modify:

```
self.tableView.contentInsets
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets
self.tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.black
```

Comment: One hackish way of doing this is might be making sure your table's frame is bigger then it's container (which must have `clipToBounds` set to true) by an amount that would hide the fading part and then adding the same amount of offset to the `contentInset.bottom` and/or `contentInset.top`.

Comment: @MihaiFratu I went ahead and tried that, did not seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably, what are you looking for is the *self.tableView.**mask*** View property:

> An optional view whose alpha channel is used to mask a view’s content.
>   The view’s alpha channel determines how much of the view’s content and
>   background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the
>   underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block
>   that content.

As the documentation says, it is an *optional* view, just set it to `nil`:

```
self.tableView.mask = nil
```

**Output:**

**Before** setting `mask` view to `nil` should be like:

[image]

**After** setting `mask` view to `nil` should be like:

[image]

**Aside bar note:**

Comparing with iOS, it seems that the `mask` view is `nil` -by default-, but *not* with tvOS. I tried both of them and the log outputs were:

For iOS:

> nil

For tvOS:

> Optional(<_UIScrollViewGradientMaskView: 0x7ff078c037f0; frame = (-90
>   -40; 1101 1200); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = >)

Comment: Wow, I spent two work days trying to solve this. It never came to mind to modify the mask. Thanks a lot !